# How to collect IIS request times

Tags: c#, iis-7

I'm trying to collect some performance metrics for IIS with a C# application. In particular I would like to get the time each request takes. Is there a performance counter for this? Or is this written into an IIS log file that I could parse (If so, is there a library for parsing this data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, IIS logs every request to the LogFiles folder (C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles)

Also by default, the last column in the log is the time taken for the request to complete.